# Why can I not execute the upgrade command in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, upgrade

I am running the following command:

```
sudo apt-get upgarde
```

In my Ubuntu 14.04 terminal, but it is outputting the following error:

```
E: Invalid operation upgarde
```

How should I solve this?

Answer (score 12):

You need to spell it correctly 'upgrade' rather than 'upgarde'!

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Answer (score 8):

This strange bug happened to me a while back. After spending hours browsing through Apt's internals and consulting Linux experts on USENET, I discovered that adding this function to my `.bashrc` fixed the problem:

```
sudo() { echo "$@" | `xargs echo $(which sudo) $(sed s/upgarde/upgrade/)`; }
```

Comment: lol (if you don't get it, just follow Arronical's answer)

Comment: Hahaha, love it.